# AppleScript save image missing value bug?

Tags: image-processing, applescript

Trying to write a simple script to convert image file to different sizes and the AppleScript keep returning me "missing value" when saving the files. Any one know what's happening in the following code?

```
set f to choose file

set image_file to f as alias

convertFile(image_file, "_512@2x.", 1024)
convertFile(image_file, "_512.", 512)

-- iPad (iOS 7+)
convertFile(image_file, "_76@2x.", 152)
convertFile(image_file, "_76.", 76)

-- iPad (iOS 6)
convertFile(image_file, "_72@2x.", 144)
convertFile(image_file, "_72.", 72)

-- iPhone (iOS 7+)
convertFile(image_file, "_60@3x.", 180)
convertFile(image_file, "_60@2x.", 120)
convertFile(image_file, "_60.", 60)

-- iPhone (iOS 6)
convertFile(image_file, "_57@2x.", 114)
convertFile(image_file, "_57.", 57)

-- iPhone (iOS 7 Spotlight)
convertFile(image_file, "_40@2x.", 80)
convertFile(image_file, "_40.", 40)

-- iPhone (iOS 5,6 Spotlight, iOS 5-7 Settings)
convertFile(image_file, "_29@2x.", 58)
convertFile(image_file, "_29.", 29)

on convertFile(source_file, file_spec, image_size)
    set my_path to POSIX path of source_file

    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "/"
    set path_parts to text items of my_path
    if last item of path_parts is not "" then
        set file_name to last item of path_parts
        set file_path to items 1 thru -2 of path_parts as string
    end if

    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
    set filename_parts to text items of file_name
    set prefix to items 1 thru -2 of filename_parts as string
    set suffix to last item of filename_parts

    set target_posix_path to file_path & "/" & prefix & file_spec & suffix
    set target_posix_file to target_posix_path as POSIX file

    tell application "Image Events"
        set this_image to open source_file
        scale this_image to size image_size
        save this_image in target_posix_path
        close this_image saving no
    end tell
end convertFile
```

Event & Replies Output on my MacBook Air (Mac OS X 10.9.5):

```
tell application "AppleScript Editor"
    choose file
        --> alias "Macintosh HD:Users:william:Desktop:goro_icon:icon.png"
end tell
tell application "Image Events"
    open alias "Macintosh HD:Users:william:Desktop:goro_icon:icon.png"
        --> image "icon.png"
    scale image "icon.png" to size 1024
    save image "icon.png" as PNG in "/Users/william/Desktop/goro_icon/icon_512@2x.png"
        --> file "Macintosh HD:Users:william:Desktop:goro_icon:icon_512@2x.png"
    close image "icon.png" saving no
    open alias "Macintosh HD:Users:william:Desktop:goro_icon:icon.png"
        --> image "icon.png"
    scale image "icon.png" to size 512
    save image "icon.png" as PNG in "/Users/william/Desktop/goro_icon/icon_512.png"
        --> missing value
    close image "icon.png" saving no
    open alias "Macintosh HD:Users:william:Desktop:goro_icon:icon.png"
        --> image "icon.png"
    scale image "icon.png" to size 152
    save image "icon.png" as PNG in "/Users/william/Desktop/goro_icon/icon_76@2x.png"
        --> missing value
    close image "icon.png" saving no
    (omitted the long list of same errors..)
end tell
```

Comment: FWIW I just ran your code here on a test image (a .png file on my desktop) and it worked fine - I'm wondering if it's something specific to either your file name, the path to your file, file/directory permissions, or perhaps the suffix or file type for your input file ?

Comment: The output of my result is as follows:

  tell application "AppleScript Editor"
  choose file
   --> alias "Macintosh HD:Users:william:Desktop:goro_icon:icon.png"
 end tell
 tell application "Image Events"
  open alias "Macintosh HD:Users:william:Desktop:goro_icon:icon.png"
   --> image "icon.png"
  scale image "icon.png" to size 512
  save image "icon.png" as PNG in "/Users/william/Desktop/goro_icon/icon_512.png"
   --> missing value
  close image "icon.png" saving no
...
 end tell

Comment: I think the only further thing I can tell you is that I'm running OS X 10.10.1 (Yosemite), and maybe also suggest trying a different input file.

Comment: The strange thing is that the script can process the first conversion and has "missing value" for the rest. If I remarked the "512@2x" line. No files can be converted... very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after trying what Paul mentioned in the comment above, I have found reason for the problem which is related to the file itself. I tried the script with another file and the script works without problem.

Opened the file in an editor and exported a new file with the same dimension (so the file looks the same but with different size). The new file worked. So the problem may caused by some uncovered bugs of Image Events.